# AsyncTask isnt filling a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I've a simple `LinearLayout` with an id `content`.

I've an other layout, a relative (id = `entry`). This relative is going to be inflated several times depending of a response of a php file.

The problem is that if I manually inflate `entry` layout 4 times, it's working correctly. This is the code used:

```
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) Events.this.findViewById(R.id.content);
    for (int i=0; i<4;i++){
        RelativeLayout event = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_entry, null);
        content.addView(event);
    }
```

But now, the problem is that I can't achieve this when doing it on an AsyncTask.

AsyncTask as itself is working correctly.

- `PreExecute()` is set to do nothing.
- `OnBackground()` makes an http request to a php file hosted on my computer, and this php is returning a json with several objects from a custom class named `Event`. I save those objects into a HashMap. Hashmap is filled up correctly (Debug: `{1=Event@40dd9708, 0=Event@40dd9628}`). As you can see, two objects of Event are on the HashMap.
- `OnPostExecute()` contains this code:

  ```
  protected void onPostExecute() {
      Log.d("debugging","Omplo llistat amb"+Events.this.events.toString());
      LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) Events.this.findViewById(R.id.content);
      for (int i=0; i<Events.this.events.size()+1;i++){

          RelativeLayout event = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_entry, null);
          Event eventDesat = Events.this.events.get(""+i);
          TextView title = (TextView) event.findViewById(R.id.title);
          title.setText(eventDesat.getTitle());
          content.addView(event);
      }
  }
  ```

But it's not filling anything.

Tried things like `event.getParent().invalidate();` but with same results.

Do you understand what is happening?
I don't really see any difference between the first example code and my real code below. Note that the loop is looping twice, as it should.

**Seems that onPostExecute is never triggered:**

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("login", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int loggedin = settings.getInt("logged", 0);
        if (loggedin == 0){
            Events.this.finish();
        }
        String username = settings.getString("username", "");
        String password = settings.getString("password", "");
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Events.this.urlWebRetrieveEvents, "POST", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        if (json!= null){
            //Log.d("Debugging", json.toString());
            try {
                int success = json.getInt("success");
                if (success == 1){
                    //this is filling hashmap correctly
                    Log.d("debugging","AQUI VAAA"+Events.this.events.toString());
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                //algo malo. no internet? perdudes les dades? Crec que mai hauriem d'entrar aquí.
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: To rule out the simple issues first... does the loop get executed? Is `Events.this.events.size()` > 0?

Comment: Why do You add 1 in condition? usually size method return results starting from 1. 0 means empty.

Comment: @Gustek just were some debugging tries, anyways shouldn't be affecting at all.

Comment: What I've just found out guys is that `onPostExecute` is never called. That `Log.d("debugging","Omplo llistat amb"+Events.this.events.toString());` isn't filling the logcat

Comment: You would get NLP if it executed or IndexOutOfBound if You use standard collection list. Post doInBackground and logcat.

Comment: @Gustek done. Logcat last msg is `AQUI VAAA{1=utils.Event@40dd9aa8, 0=utils.Event@40dd99c8}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
protected void onPostExecute() {
```

to

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Stupidest mistake ever.

My AsyncTask is like this:
`class RetrieveEvents extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{`

So I had to implement onPostExecute with an Override like this:
`protected void onPostExecute(String str) {`

Previously it was:
`protected void onPostExecute() {`